# Could not find control inside LoginView LoggedIn template

Tags: c#, asp.net, loginview

I tried to get the LoginName control inside LoginView LoggedIn template , despite several methods, the code still could not work.

I wished to change the default username to the customer name.

Here is the code:

```
 <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
   <LoggedInTemplate> 


                 Hello, <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server"></asp:LoginName>

                 <br /> 

                 <div style="text-align: right; margin-right: 5px "> 
                <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LogoutPageUrl="~/Home.aspx" Font-Underline="True" />
                </div></div>
        </LoggedInTemplate>


    </asp:LoginView>
```

at the code behind :

```
 protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        LoginName loginName = LoginView1.FindControl("LoginName1") as LoginName;
        Response.Write(loginName.ToString());  //for now I used Response.Write for testing purposes
    }
```

Comment: is LoginName1 a child of LoginView, or a child of LoggedInTemplate? It looks like you might need to go through LoggedInTemplate to get access to LoginName1.

Comment: I think it a child of LoggedInTemplate. My code is like <LoginView> followed by <LoggedInTemplate> and later it reached the LoginName1

Comment: Then it soudns like you need to find the control through LoggedInTemplate, which @AghilasYakoub below seems to have posted an example about.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
 <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
  <LoggedInTemplate> 
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUserName" Text="" />
    <br /> 
    <div style="text-align: right; margin-right: 5px "> 
    <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LogoutPageUrl="~/Home.aspx" Font-Underline="True" />
  </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

and in code behinde:

```
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    if (this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)      
       (this.LoginView1.FindControl("lblUserName") as Label).Text = "Hello, " + this.Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can try with this code

```
LoginView1.LoggedInTemplate.FindControl("LoginName1") as LoginName;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I had tried your method, but it gave this error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginView.LoggedInTemplate.get'

Comment: i'am sorry i modifed the name of control LoginView1, try with LoginView1 not LoginView

Comment: Thanks for replying, but now there is a problem with the FindControl statement and the error is : 'System.Web.UI.ITemplate' does not contain a definition for 'FindControl' and no extension method 'FindControl' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.ITemplate' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)